# usage of "to impugn"

Tags: word-usage

According to the online dictionary www.collinsdictionary.com, to impugn means to attack by argument or criticism; oppose or challenge as false or questionable.

I am wondering if I can use this verb in my example below.

(ex) Yesterday, Tom and Mary proofread Jack's essay and gave him feedback. Disagreeing with her, Tom **impugned** her comments by making contradictory remarks. Their disagreement resulted in a heated argument.

Am I using the verb "to impugn" correctly?

Comment: The usage is technically correct, but the word is rarely seen in this context. In current usage, it is usually a person's trait (such as honesty or integrity) that is impugned, rather than a comment or statement. Chambers has _"to call into question or raise doubts about (the honesty, integrity, etc of someone or something); to criticize or challenge."_

Comment: See [_Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms_](https://books.google.com/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA227&dq=impugn). It's a little bit dated, but it's a great resource for this and similar questions. To really get a feeling for this word, though, you'll need to see many examples of it in [real usage](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=impugn).

Comment: @BenKovitz The holy OED really comes a cropper on this one, with no mention at all of the current usage. I find **[Chambers](http://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=impugn&title=21st)** to be an excellent source these days, very concise and with good contemporaneity.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Hmm, indeed not their best work. The entry history says it was last updated in 1989, by which time I think the usage of impugning character was well established. They've sure got [_cropper_](http://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=cropper&_searchBtn=Search) well covered, though. :)

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you are using the word correctly, but it sounds strange to me in that context. Additional context could make it appropriate, though it would be an unusual kind of context; see below.

First of all, **impugn** is a very formal word. If you search [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=impugn), you'll find that many of the leading contexts where it appears are legal proceedings, many are from the 19th century, and many involve disputes about religion or religious condemnation.

Second, as with many English words, it helps to look at their etymology to understand their connotations—and their connections with other words. The **-pugn** part of the word comes from a Latin root meaning "fist". The **im-** part comes from a Latin root meaning to oppose or attack (charging "into" the enemy). You can see these same roots in other words:

- **pugnacious**: eager to get into a fight, such as a fistfight.
- **pugilism**: a fancy word for the sport of [boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pugilism_(disambiguation)).
- **repugnant**: offensive, repulsive; in law, a condition or clause that contradicts the contract or legal principle that it's part of, in effect attacking or opposing its own basis, or opposing the moral, civilized attitude that is the basis of law.
- **invade**: to enter a foreign country with an army, as during war or starting a war.
- **insurrection**: a violent uprising against a government by its own citizens; a rebellion.

**Impugn** echoes these connotations of hostility and penetrating attack, primarily in regard to a proposition. It means to throw doubt on it, criticizing it relentlessly, in many ways, as if pummeling it, especially in a dispute about religion or in an argument in a court of law.

The word "comments", however, suggests minor, insubstantial remarks, not a weighty matter. So, it sounds incongruous to say "Tom impugned her comments." That makes me dimly imagine something like repeatedly punching a sheet of wet tissue paper; it's too much force for the thing being attacked. If you *want* to suggest that jarring connotation, though, then **impugn** could be a good choice, though it would be best supported by something stronger than "contradictory remarks". Maybe you could say "Tom impugned her comments, fulminating over every word choice, denouncing every comma, pounding on every fault, no matter how minor." In other words, Tom isn't simply disagreeing, he's being hostile in a prolonged way that's not suitable for mere comments made in the course of proofreading.

Usually even in regard to a proposition, **impugn** suggests attacking the *person* or somehow attacking the source of the proposition. Most often in contemporary usage, **impugn** means to bring up information suggesting that someone has low moral character, so they can't be trusted, or throwing doubt on their trustworthiness. [Garner's Dictionary of Modern Legal Usage](https://books.google.com/books?id=35dZpfMmxqsC&pg=PA427&dq=impugn) gives these examples:

> A most unfortunate result is that, to support its holding, the court, despite its disclaimers, **impugns** the **integrity** of public school teachers.

In other words, it is a shame that the court is casting doubt on the integrity of public school teachers. The court appears to be attacking public school teachers in order to defend itself.

> The **ethical standards** of the wife's solicitors have never been **impugned**.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, when I hear "impugn," the connotation is nearly always about the subject's character. P. E. Dant was on the right track above, specifically with [the point](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133547/usage-of-to-impugn#comment269778_133547)

> usually a person's trait (such as honesty or integrity) that is impugned

I'm not familiar with the Collins Dictionary, but I think [Wordsmith's definition](https://wordsmith.org/words/impugn.html)--" To call in question or cast doubt upon"--is closer to how the term is actually being used. That said, "impugn" is not really a word you hear in daily conversation. It is more for when people are trying to be very precise.

Your example might not be outright incorrect in the strictest sense, but it is certainly unusual. A native speaker might do a double take upon seeing it.

I wonder if you were thinking of the similar word **repugn** for your phrase, which your own preferred Collins Dictionary agrees [means "oppose" or "conflict with"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/repugn)?

Comment: There are many English speakers who employ the wealth of expression afforded by the English vocabulary, even in casual discourse, without attempting to sound "fancy". When buying something to bang up for dinner, I may not "impugn" the fishmonger's honesty when he quotes an absurdly high price for sole, but I will use the word in conversation with my peers over the resultant meal because it most precisely expresses my thought. It does not benefit new learners of the language to imply that a deep vocabulary is something deserving of even mild derision.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I must admit, your comment rankled me a bit at first because I did not intend to imply anything about derision at all. In fact, I happen to be quite proud of my own large vocabulary. However, upon re-reading my answer, I can see how what I originally wrote could be interpreted in the way you were talking about. As it was not integral to the body of the answer, I've simply removed it entirely. I do thank you for letting me know--truly--but would suggest a different phrasing should a similar situation occur. I.e. "A negative effect might occur" rather than "your intent was bad."

Comment: _Rankle_ is a perfect example of the wealth and depth of our vocabulary. Why, it's right up there with _impugn._ Of course we don't want learners to come off trying to sound like a lot of toffee-nose prats, but I think we benefit them when we show the full range of wonders available in their new language. I don't use _impugn_ when I'm trying to be precise, though: I use it when it expresses my thought. Quick now: can you think of a synonym?

Comment: Just got round to reading your comment again, and I really did not think nor imply that I thought that "your intent was bad". When one uses the word "fancy" in reference to speech or dress in the U.S. vernacular, the intention is almost always to express mild derision. It may be that this vernacular is not yours. If so, I unfortunately misconstrued your use of the word, and offer my apology. It is, of course, certainly true that there are yahoos who _do_ impugn the character (or virility if a male) of anyone who uses "fancy words". They rankle me!